# How to create a Web Popup Window without referring to a new html file?

Tags: php, html, popup

How do you create a Web Popup Window without referring to a new html file?

All the codes I've found requires to refer to a new file where the popup document sits.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `about:blank` as the target:

```
window.open('about:blank', 'name_of_window', 'popup');
```

If you want to manually construct a document:

```
var popup = window.open('about:blank', 'name_of_window', 'popup');
if (!popup) { // popup is `null` if the window is blocked
    // Otherwise, popup is the Window object of the popup
    popup.document.write('Test');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is JavaScript. What were you expecting?